Pass element form character vector in loop to function and use in assign
I have a function that chooses, reads and formats Excel reports from Workday, and produces data.frames. I've simplified for purposes of begging for your help. :-)
In the function, I pass a parameter called df_name. I want to pass this parameter in a loop to produce many data.frames in a single call.
library(openxlsx)
read_report <- function(
     df_name=NULL
     wb= loadWorkbook(paste0(file_path))
     file_path <- choose.files(multi = FALSE, filters = cbind("Excel (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"), caption = "Select Excel File")
          df_data <- read.xlsx(wb,1,colNames = TRUE)
     assign(substitute(df_name), df_data, envir=.GlobalEnv)
)

I have a vector of character strings list_dfs that represent the names of different data.frames:
list_dfs <- c("df_workers", "df_headcount", "df_terms")

I have a loop that iterates list_df which passes the parameter df_name the function  read_report
for (i in list_dfs) {
   read_report(df_name = i)
}

This line causes the function to break.
assign(substitute(df_name), df_data, envir=.GlobalEnv)

What's goofy is that when I do this, as I do routinely, outside of a loop, I have no problem, as in the following:
read_report(df_name = "df_workers")

Why does that line choke on the variable i, which is of character type, and not the explicit parameter df_worker?
I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

I'd suggest to return a dataframe from the function. Then use lapply to call that function, the outputs from the lapply will be then assigned to a list object that would hold all the dataframes.
Something like this (not tested):
read_report <- function(df_name = NULL){
  file_path <- choose.files(multi = FALSE,
                            filters = cbind("Excel (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"), 
                            caption = "Select Excel File")
  wb = loadWorkbook(paste0(file_path))
  df_data <- read.xlsx(wb, 1, colNames = TRUE)
  return(df_data)
  }

list_dfs <- c("df_workers", "df_headcount", "df_terms")

myList <- lapply(list_dfs, read_report)

Also, note, there was a typo in your function definition. It is fixed.

The paste0() you left in the code is still nonsensical.

@KonradRudolph it is, I think they have some private path that needs pasting, they would not want to share here.

First, thank you for answering this question. However, the result of the code in your answer is a list of data.frames that remain "unnamed". It's as though the elements of list_dfs were not applied to the elements of myList. In the OP, outside the loop, the data.frames are named.

@DavidWeisser We have the names, just assign: names(myList) <- list_dfs
